# Java Swing Program- Input from GUI to Main getting stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, user-input

I have a Java program where I plan to take input from GUI, and use that input later for processing in `main()`. I am using `Eclipse`.
I am sending an `HW` object(called `HWObj`) to the GUI `JFrame`, and checking for a `boolean` field in the object to continue processing in `main()`.

InputWindow is custom object which extends `JPanel` implements `ActionListener`
It contains a reference to the current `JFrame`(parentFrame). On clicking a `JButton` in InputWindow, I have written a custom `ActionListener` which sets the value of `HWObj`.check to true and disposes the parentFrame. This should cause execution to resume in `main()`.
Code for `HW` class is as below :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class HW {

    //globals
    boolean check;
    public HW() {
        //initialisations
        check = false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        final HW problem = new HW();
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //Create and set up the window.
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Select folders");
                    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
                    frame.setResizable(false);
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    InputWindow Directories = new InputWindow(problem, frame);
                    Directories.setOpaque(true);
                    frame.add(Directories);
                    //Display the window.
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        while(!problem.finish);
        //Do processing on problem
        System.out.println("Done");
    } 
}
```

The `Actionlistener` in the gui is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputWindow extends JPanel
                implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4228345704162790878L;

    HW problem;
    JFrame parentFrame;
    //more globals

    public InputWindow(HW problem, JFrame parentFrame) {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        this.parentFrame = parentFrame;
        this.problem = problem;

        JButton finishButton = new JButton("Finish");
        finishButton.setActionCommand("fin");
        finishButton.addActionListener(this);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        this.add(finishButton, gbc);

        //Initialize buttons and text areas and labels
        //Code removed for ease of reading

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if(command.equals("fin")) {
            //Do a lot of stuff, then   
            this.removeAll();
            parentFrame.dispose();
            problem.check = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked, and the control to this function comes normally on button click.

Now, I would expect it to return to `main`, and exit the `while` loop, and continue processing.
This does not happen. The debugger in eclipse shows only the main thread running, and when I try to pause it, I see that the thread is stuck in the `while` loop. But if I try to step through, it exits the `while` loop as expected, and continues. However, it gets remains stuck in the `while` loop until I manually try to debug it.
What is the problem? Why is it not resuming the `main thread` as expected?
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Would require complete code.

Comment: The complete code is huge and bloated. Could you please tell me which parts you would like?

Comment: Code of the class which creates a new frame and later destroys it, and the one which you have stuck while loop.

Comment: the 'relevant' parts would be nice. it would be a lot easier to read if you had extracted code to methods, rather than to stuff your main method with code. the main method should do nothing, except just kick-starting your application.

Comment: which parts you would like? == post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, generating a.m. issue

Comment: True. I have extracted most of the other code to functions. The ones for the GUI remain. Ill move those too.

Comment: @Stultuske we are always tried to reduce lottery here, reason why [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) exists

Comment: I'll get you a SSCCE/MCVE as fast as I can

Comment: The above shall compile and run

Comment: You have an error in your code, the loop should be `while(!problem.check);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is to do with how the Java memory model works. The loop in your main thread will be checking a stale value of `check`.

When you enter the debugger, the memory is forced to be updated, so that's why it starts working at that point.

If you mark your variable as `volatile`, that will force the JVM to ensure that all threads are using the up-to-date value:

```
volatile boolean check;
```

You can read more about `volatile` and the Java memory model in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4).

Comment: Such optimizations happen for C, but are you sure that this happens in Java too?

Comment: @TSG It is not an optimisation per se, it's more to do with how the java memory model works.  I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @TSG Once I thought more deeply about it, I have in fact completely changed the explaination! (but not the solution...) :)

Comment: Thanks. Using volatile solves the problem. Do you think that using a JDialog would have been a more appropriate method, as proposed in the other answer by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: In this scenario, a JDialog would work because it blocks the thread that sets it visible until the dialog completes.  That's not appropriate if you wanted to actually do something in your main thread.  You might also consider using a different approach to your inter-thread communication, rather than busy waiting on a volatile variable.  I'll update my answer with an example for you.

Comment: My dialog is used to get input for a number of directories etc. This data needs to return to main for further computation.

Comment: @TSG What I mean is if you wanted to do something in main *while* the dialog is showing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a JFrame where you should be using a modal JDialog. If you use the modal JDialog for an input window, you will know exactly when it is "finished" since code flow will resume from the calling code from right after when the dialog was set visible.

Either that or if you are trying to swapviews, then use a CardLayout to swap your view, and use an observer type pattern to listen for change of state.

Comment: Thanks. I do not need to swap views. I just need to wait for an input before continuing. I'll check JDialog

Comment: @TSG: `My dialog is used to get input for a number of directories etc. This data needs to return to main for further computation.` -- then you should use a modal JDialog. But use what you want since it's your project.